# R: How to perform an "outer product" between a vector and a list

Tags: r, list, lapply

I've got a vector`V <- c("a","b","c","d","e")`

and a list `L` that looks like this:

```
> str(L)
List of 2
 $ A:List of 2
  ..$ alpha: num 1
  ..$ beta : num 2
 $ B:List of 2
  ..$ alpha: num 1
  ..$ beta : num 2
```

I need to spread out the elements of `V` into `L` like doing an outer product with arrays so that it eventually looks like this:

```
> str(L3)
List of 5
 $ a:List of 2
  ..$ A:List of 3
  .. ..$ alpha: num 1
  .. ..$ beta : num 2
  .. ..$ gamma: chr "a"
  ..$ B:List of 3
  .. ..$ alpha: num 1
  .. ..$ beta : num 2
  .. ..$ gamma: chr "a"
 $ b:List of 2
  ..$ A:List of 3
  .. ..$ alpha: num 1
  .. ..$ beta : num 2
  .. ..$ gamma: chr "b"
  ..$ B:List of 3
  .. ..$ alpha: num 1
  .. ..$ beta : num 2
  .. ..$ gamma: chr "b"
 $ c:List of 2
  ..$ A:List of 3
  .. ..$ alpha: num 1
  .. ..$ beta : num 2
  .. ..$ gamma: chr "c"
  ..$ B:List of 3
  .. ..$ alpha: num 1
  .. ..$ beta : num 2
  .. ..$ gamma: chr "c"
 $ d:List of 2
  ..$ A:List of 3
  .. ..$ alpha: num 1
  .. ..$ beta : num 2
  .. ..$ gamma: chr "d"
  ..$ B:List of 3
  .. ..$ alpha: num 1
  .. ..$ beta : num 2
  .. ..$ gamma: chr "d"
 $ e:List of 2
  ..$ A:List of 3
  .. ..$ alpha: num 1
  .. ..$ beta : num 2
  .. ..$ gamma: chr "e"
  ..$ B:List of 3
  .. ..$ alpha: num 1
  .. ..$ beta : num 2
  .. ..$ gamma: chr "e"
```

Notice that the elements in V not only appear inside the each sub-sub-list, it also serve as the name of each sub-list.

What I have come up with is this:

```
L3 <- lapply(V, function(x) lapply(L,function(y) c(y,gamma = x)))
L3 <- setNames(L3, V)
```

The nested `lapply` function looks ugly and counter-intuitive to me. I tried to eliminate it by trying the `outer` function in base R but clearly that doesn't work. So I'm looking for a solution that is still "functional" but cleaner and more intuitive. Thanks!

P.S. I'm learning `rlist` recently and found it quite handy, so an `rlist` solution is also very weclomed. @kun-ren

Comment: Seems like you have a pretty good method already

Comment: @RichardScriven Actually I'm keen to see a `rlist` solution. I think it should have something to do with `list.map` and `list.update`, but I haven't quite figured out how to translate `lapply` to `list.map`.

Comment: @RichardScriven I saw your deleted answer. It's a mixed approach but it's certainly informative. Thanks.

Comment: I undeleted it.  Guess I'll leave it there but I don't feel great about it.  Could probably make it better if I knew that package a little better.

Comment: @RichardScriven BTW, can I mention the author of the `rlist` package here? I'm not sure if it's allowed in SO.

Comment: I don't really know what the protocol is on that, but I certainly wouldn't mind if someone pinged me with a question about my package.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `rlist` but just from tinkering it looks like you can do

```
library(rlist)
setNames(Map(list.update, rep(list(L), length(V)), gamma = V), V)
```

But it doesn't seem any better than what you've already done with `lapply()`.  The `str()` looks the same as what you have in the question though.

**Data:**

```
L <- structure(list(A = structure(list(alpha = 1, beta = 2), .Names = c("alpha", 
"beta")), B = structure(list(alpha = 1, beta = 2), .Names = c("alpha", 
"beta"))), .Names = c("A", "B"))
```